# Retrieve specific array value in JSON - angular 5

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve specific value("isRight") in jSON.Tried various solutions present on stackoverflow and matched my code with one of them,but I'm getting the value as undefined.(With no error)
JSON:

```
{

        "QuestionID" : "1",
        "Question"   :"The ozone layer restricts: ",
        "OP"         :["X-rays and gamma rays" , 
                       "Visible light", 
                       "Infrared radiation", 
                       "Ultraviolet radiation" ],
          "isRight"  :"Ultraviolet radiation"

    },


    {


        "QuestionID" : "2",
        "Question"   :"The length of the bridge, which a train 130 metres long and travelling at 45 km/hr can cross in 30 seconds, is:",
        "OP"         :["200 m" , 
                       "225 m", 
                       "245 m", 
                       "250 m" ],
          "isRight"  :"245 m"

    },
```

.ts:

```
 filterAnswer(i:number)
      {
      for(i=1 ; i <= this.questArrayNew1.length ; i++)

      {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(this.questArrayNew1);
        this.isRyt  = this.questArrayNew1.find(x=>x.QuestionID == i).isRight;


      }
      }
```

I want to store the value retrieved in variable 'isRyt' .

Comment: Do you actually need to do `array#find`? If each element of the array has `QuestionID` = element index in the array, you can simply do `this.isRyt  = this.questArrayNew1[i].isRight;` Also, you are overriding `this.isRyt` at each iteration, I don't think this is what you want to do

Comment: Yes bugs,I need to override this.isRyt at every iteration

Comment: Fair enough, does the proposed solution help you?

Comment: Throwing an error: Cannot read propery 'isRight' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code given by you, the 'QuestionID' is string but 'i' is a number, So it should give an error like `'The '==' operator can not be applied to the 'string' and 'number' types'` . I am getting this  error when checking your code.

So first try to compare in between same datatype. May be for this reason your comparison `x=>x.QuestionID == i` is getting failed and the value is undefined.

Put `"QuestionID" : 1` instead of `"QuestionID" : "1"`

After correcting that you will get the isRyt value like this:[image]

I think you are expecting this result.

Comment: Great that it helped you..then please up-vote and accept this as answer

Comment: I upvoted it bud but how do I accept this as a answer? Sorry Im new to stackoverflow

Comment: No problem..The answer you want to select will have a grey checkmark below the UP/DOWN arrows in the top left corner of the answer. Click on the checkmark! Once it becomes green, the answer is accepted. And if you have enough reputation, you can upvote also. You can refer the link  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358868/how-can-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
{
         this.isRyt  = this.questArrayNew1.find(x=>{
              if(x.QuestionID === i){ return x.isRight }
})}
```

Comment: Throwing an error for statement after "find(" as : Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'